# How can I Dockeries a python script which contains spark dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pyspark, dockerfile

I have a Python file, in which I tried to import Spark libraries.
When I built it with the Docker File it is giving me error as 'JAVA_HOME' is not set.
I tried to install Java through Docker file, but it is giving error as well.
Below is the Dockerfile I tried to execute.

```
FROM python:3.6.4
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean 

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

ADD Samplespark.py /
COPY Samplespark.py /opt/ml/Samplespark.py

RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pyspark
RUN pip install sklearn
RUN pip install sagemaker_pyspark
RUN pip install sagemaker

CMD [ "python", "./Samplespark.py" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["python","/opt/ml/Samplespark.py"]
```

Please help me to install the Java dependencies for PySpark in Docker.

Comment: Is the java installation successful? What is the error after adding step to install java?

How I would have debugged it. First I will start container and then run the Samplespark.py inside the container.

Comment: I think `echo oracle-java7-installer ` should be `echo oracle-java8-installer`.

Comment: Hi @ASR and @ashwinids, I am getting below error after and before replacing the suggested text. `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Debian os, not ubuntu os. These ppas are for ubuntu os. According to [this](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-install-java-8-on-debian-jessie/349), article oracle java8 is not available in Debian due to licensing issues.
You have following options-
1. Use an Ubuntu docker image which comes with preinstalled oracle java8 like this [one](https://hub.docker.com/r/mlaccetti/docker-oracle-java8-ubuntu-16.04/)
2. Follow this [tutorial](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-install-java-8-on-debian-jessie/349/2) on how to install Oracle java8 on Debian Jessie
3. Install open_jdk `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`

Comment: Thanks @ashwinids, I tried with #1, it solved the Java issue, but I am getting error for statement `RUN pip install pyspark`, how would I install the pySpark dependency in it?
The error displays as `KILLED` withoud any message.

Comment: I think the process is getting killed because of the OOM(out of memory error). Try to increase the memory of container. Since your original issue is solved, please accept the answer